# Binary search tree in C++ 17 using iterator pattern

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, c++17

I am new to C++ and am attempting to write the following binary search tree using the iterator pattern (and `std::optional` in C++17):

```
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <stack>

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
  BinarySearchTree(T key)
  : key_(key),
    left_(nullptr),
    right_(nullptr) {}

  BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree& bst) {
    key_ = bst.key_;
    left_ = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree>(*bst.left_);
    right_ = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree>(*bst.right_);
  }

  void insert(T key);

  T key() { return key_; }
  std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree> left() { return std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree>(*left_); }
  std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree> right() { return std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree>(*right_); }

private:
  T key_;
  std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree> left_;
  std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree> right_;
};

template <typename T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(T key) {
  auto insert = [key](auto& node) {
    if (node) {
      node->insert(key);
    } else {
      node = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree>(key);
    }
  };

  if (key <= key_) {
    insert(left_);
  } else {
    insert(right_);
  }
}

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTreeIterator {
public:
  BinarySearchTreeIterator(BinarySearchTree<T>& bst, bool forward)
  : bst_(std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree<T>>(bst)),
    forward_(forward) {}

  std::optional<T> operator*() { return current_; }

  void operator++() {
    while (bst_ || !stack_.empty()) {
      if (bst_) {
        stack_.emplace(std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree<T>>(*bst_));
        bst_ = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree<T>>(*(forward_ ? bst_->left() : bst_->right()));
      } else {
        bst_ = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree<T>>(*(stack_.top()));
        stack_.pop();
        current_ = bst_->key();
        bst_ = std::make_unique<BinarySearchTree<T>>(*(forward_ ? bst_->right() : bst_->left()));
        break;
      }
    }
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree<T>> bst_;
  bool forward_;
  std::stack<std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree<T>>> stack_;
  std::optional<T> current_;
};
```

I am not sure if my usage of `std::unique_ptr` is correct or idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `BinarySearchTree`

- Since the tree isn't balanced, worst case insertion complexity is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ (and not \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$ as likely intended). (Same for lookup, if such a method were to be added).
- Calling `left()` or `right()` will create a copy of the whole left/right subtree. This is very likely not intended.
- This class could profit a lot from a move constructor and a move assignment operator overload. (And while we're at it, add a copy assignment operator overload and a destructor to complete the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).)
- Is it really necessary to name the lambda the same as the enclosing function in `BinarySearchTree::insert(T key)`?
- Also of note, only types that can be copied can be inserted into the `BinarySearchTree`. This means it is currently not possibly to store a move-only type (like `std::unique_ptr`) in the tree. (This capacity could be added with an overload accepting a `T&&`.
- `BinarySearchTree::insert(T key)` creates unnecessary copies of `key` for each recursive call. Consider taking a `const T&` instead.`
- `left_` and `right_` are often dereferenced without checking them for `nullptr` beforehand! This results in undefined behavior if they are `nullptr`!

## `BinarySearchTreeIterator`

- This iterator doesn't provide any `iterator_traits` or an `end` iterator. This means using it with standard library algorithms (or even a range based `for` loop) is not possible. More info on [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) and [iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).
- There are lots and lots of unnecessary copies (basically every time `std::make_unique` or `bst_->left()` or `bst_->right()` are called).
- `current_` will always have a value with this implementation, so making it `std::optional<T>` is misleading. Also, any modifications done to the value returned by `operator*()` won't be propagated to the original `BinarySearchTree` entry (as it returns an independent copy and not a reference).
- This iterator traverses the tree in-order. Since there are also other traversal methods, like pre-order, post-order or level-order, it would be nice to indicate that in the name.

## `std::unique_ptr` usage

Normally, a `std::unique_ptr` is used to express "I own this". So a signature like `std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree<T>> BinarySearchTree::left()` says "Call me, and you become the new owner of whatever I return".

Is this necessary in this case? No! After all, the caller just wants to access the existing object, and not acquire a new one.

So, how can this be expressed?

There are two variants:

1. **Return a non-owning `BinarySearchTree<T>*`.**

   Pros:

   - Very lightweight.
   - Very simple (can still use `std::unique_ptr` for internal storage, so resources get cleaned up properly).

   Cons:

   - If the `BinarySearchTree<T>` gets destroyed, but someone still has the pointer stored, the pointer is dangling.
   - Someone could prematurely call `delete` on the pointer (so the internal `std::unique_ptr` would be dangling).
2. **Return a `std::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTree<T>>`.**

   Pros:

   - As long as the `std::shared_ptr` exists, the object will be valid.

   Cons:

   - Might keep the tree (or subtrees) alive for far longer than intended.
   - Has a slight overhead.
   - Requires using `std::shared_ptr` for internal storage.
   - Might leak in case of cycles (not a problem here, just for the general case).

   Of course, some of those problems can be avoided by appropriate use of `std::weak_ptr`.

Some more resources:

- [CppCon 2014 talk about smart pointers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64)
- [CppCon 2016 talk about memory management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) (even talks specifically about trees and graphs)

Comment: I would prefer turning a reference from left/right as it makes it clear that it is not a pointer that you should store because it can be destroyed at any point

Comment: @EmilyL.: The node might be `nullptr`, though, so you'd return a dangling reference in those cases. Sadly, there are no `std::optional<T&>` :/

Comment: Now that you mention it yes. But that's also a problem with ops current code that directly dereferences and copy constructs from a possibly null-ptr.

Comment: @EmilyL.: Oh, yeah. I was so taken in with all the extra copies that I completely overlooked the `nullptr` dereferences.